# Setting a property on a parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I am using react-router and redux and I have the following `App` component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <PageTitle title="Projects" />

        <div className="page-content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This component is then used in react-route:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={ProjectsList} />
    <Route path="projects/:id" component={ProjectsShow} />
  </Route>
);
```

I want to set the `title` attribute on the `<PageTitle title="Projects" />` component dynamically, based on the router component I am currently rendering.

Some of the components can't have a fixed title, because they depend on the information of the project I am currently displaying, so if the project is called *My Project*, that's the title I want to display.

I am also using `redux-promise` to resolve all my promises, and I need to somehow update this external component based on the result of a promise on my component. Here's an example:

```
class ProjectsShow extends Component {
  static contextTypes = { router: PropTypes.object };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchProject(this.props.params.id);
    // I want to set the title of the `PageTitle` component
    // when this fetch is resolved
  }

  // (...)
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could implement this?

Comment: easiest way is to include `PageTitle` in each child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extra action for changing the title, create a reducer, and connect the resulting state to your component.

```
function reducer(state="Default title", action) {
    switch SET_TITLE:
        return action.title
    ...
}
```

Then wrap your PageTitle component with connect() from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)

This is exactly the kind of scenario redux can do well.

Comment: The tricky part was finding the appropriate place to set the title, because using react-redux forbids calling an action from inside the render method (which makes sense). So I ended up calling the action inside `componentDidUpdate` and it worked perfectly.